# XML response has no "auth" node and Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie

Tags: vpn, ubuntu-18.04, cisco

"When connecting to VPN using OpenConnect on the Ubuntu 18.04 platform, OpenConnect installed successfully with the command:

```
$ sudo apt install openconnect
```

However, upon trying to connect using the command:

```
$ openconnect https://xxx.xx.xxx/
```

the following errors occurred:

```
Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie 

I don't have additional details about these errors. If anyone has a solution to these VPN errors, please revert back."
```

Comment: I thibk this question should be asked at the [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com) Community.

Comment: hey, thank you @Gourav